# Min dominating set software

Tags: np-hardness, software

I need a fast min-dominating-set code for some complexity lower bounds research I am doing.

I could transform to SAT and use an off the shelf SAT solver; but I was hoping min-dom-set had something out there comparable to [Cliquer](http://users.aalto.fi/~pat/cliquer.html) for max-clique.

Suggestions?

--Update--
Currently using Z3 SMT Optimize Python bindings subject to minimizing sum of dominating vertices. 0 = default, 1 = dominating. Sum of vertex and neighborhood must be >= 1 for each vertex. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/blob/master/graph_optimization_z3.py).

Comment: You might want to look at SMT solvers as well.

Comment: I'm fine shelling out to an SMT solver also. I would love it if anybody had a script that reduced directed graphs into SMT-LIB MIN-DOM-SET formulations.

Comment: Here is a Python formulation for graph coloring using SMT-LIB solvers as a back end, https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground/blob/master/graph_coloring_z3.py

Comment: My first inclination would be to use a commercial Integer Programming solver like Gurobi. If you're working from a university IP address, you can get a free academic license.

Comment: Nah. I want it all open source.